# How to tell if the “clusters” I see in my pair plots are statistically significant or occurring by random chance?

Tags: statistics, clustering, mathematics

I have a data set with one row per subject. Some variables include laboratory parameters for blood chemistry, hematology, etc. I also have some flag variables: any = 1 if the subject experienced an adverse event, 0 if not; and ser_flag = 1 if the subject experienced a serious adverse event, 0 if not.

There doesn't seem to be any difference in the distribution of laboratory parameters between subjects who experienced an adverse event (any=1) and subjects who did not (any = 0). When I do a pair plot of all the lab parameters against each other and color by the any flag, there doesn't seem to be any clustering or separation of subjects.

However, when I do the same pair plot and color by ser_flag - I notice that the 20 subjects who experienced a serious adverse events seem to be clustered together in many of the plots.

What test (if any) can I use to determine if these clusters I think I am seeing are occurring randomly, by chance...or if they statistically significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding clustering in machine learning, there is the [Hopkin's statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins_statistic) which basically compares your data to randomly generated data and returns a score of how *likely your data shows tendencies of clusters*.
However, you need to be able to define a distance function between two data points which I don't know is possible in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for this! Gives me something interesting to research!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest test is equality of means of two distributions. [Student's t-test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)